# Unable to resolve host when POSTing

Tags: http, tcp, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I've hit a roadblock when trying to post to a server. I've made a child of the TCPLink class with the following Opened() even (the GET function works)

```
event Opened()
{  
    //let the php file know what's coming
    WorldInfo.Game.Broadcast(self, "REQUEST TEXT: " $ RequestText);
    if(bGetData){
        SendText("GET /"$TargetPath$"?"$RequestText$" HTTP/1.0"$chr(13)$chr(10));
    }else{
        SendText("POST /"$TargetPath$" HTTP/1.0"$chr(13)$chr(10));
        WorldInfo.Game.Broadcast(self, "SENDING POST");
        `log("---------------------------SENDING POST-------------------------");
    }
    SendText("Host: "$TargetHost$chr(13)$chr(10));
    SendText("User-Agent: HTTPTool/1.0"$Chr(13)$Chr(10));
    SendText("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"$chr(13)$chr(10));
    SendText("Content-Length: "$len(RequestText)$Chr(13)$Chr(10));
    SendText(chr(13)$chr(10));
    //send securitykey, command and params for php to use
    SendText(RequestText);
    SendText(chr(13)$chr(10));
    SendText("Connection: Close");
    SendText(chr(13)$chr(10)$chr(13)$chr(10));
}
```

I know it attempts to send the post (I see the Broadcast and log messages) but the log displays this error:

```
[0042.56] ScriptLog: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://hosting.zymic.com/forum-spam">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your hosting company closed down your website due to spam issues?
Sending requests like this several times will probably flag you as a spammer.

Comment: Whomp wah :( any ideas on who hosts game dev servers without flagging them as spam?